# copy contents dynamic view to a string

Tags: xpages

Well , I have a dynamic view : With a search scoped variable I am selecting documents in the view and updating the panel in which the view resides. So far so good.
But as in my previous post ( [copy contents view to 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895761/copy-contents-view-to-2-strings) )
I would like to copy the view data of a column to a string.

The solution Simon gave me works when you want to copy the data from the complete view ,

```
<xp:this.data>
   <xp:dominoView var="view2"
    viewName="<<viewName>>">
</xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>

<xp:inputText>
<xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
 var length = view2.getEntryCount();
 var entries = view2.getAllEntries();
 var i = 0;
 var currentEntry = entries.getFirstEntry();
 var list = "";

 while(i < length)
 {
    list += currentEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(1);

    currentEntry = entries.getNextEntry();
    i++;
 }

 return list;
}]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:inputText>
```

but doesn't copy the data of the data of my dynamic view .(I bound it to a button on which I click after the refresh of the view)

Answer (score 0):

The line: var entries = view2.getAllEntries(); needs to be changed to reflect the search scoped variable instead of the entire view.

Comment: Any idea how to do that ? Let's say the scoped variable = searchString
  I could of course go trough each entry and compare them with the scoped variable , but there must be a better way , I hope ....